# Не работает nginx 1.11.1 на ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Установил чистую ubuntu 14.04, установил nginx 1.11.1 из репозитория разработчика, браузер по айпиадресу не открывается. При команде:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo: systemctl: command not found
```

Comment: а что значит : чистая убунта ?

Comment: Никаких программ, серверов, php не устанавливалось, только убунта и следом nginx.

Comment: т.е ни каких зависимостей не установленно ?

Comment: Сергей я когда то делал по этому мануальчику и всё работало , но дополнительно смотрел youtube , вот мануал https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/

Comment: А с чем зависимости? Единственно есть utw брандмауэр. На 16 убунте проблем не было, сразу всё работало и страница проверки показывала, что он запущен. А сейчас у хостера только 14 убунта и нужна версия старше 1.8 nginx, поэтому пришлось установить из репозитория разработчика. После установки показывает версию nginx, но команды не работают для него.

Comment: погоди - вот на youtube видос мне тоже тогда помог очень сильно https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RR9MJxm0eVk

Comment: Спасибо, но я по нему же сделал. Тут видимо какой-то несрост версии убунту и nginx. И по видео те же команды.

Comment: у меня всё получалось , а sudo apt-get update и sudo apt-get upgrade делали ?

Comment: Делал, затем apt-get dist-upgrade. Без него тоже пробовал, только: apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y Вы так же из репозитория разработчика пробовали? Дело в том, что если из самой убунту устанавливать, то версия nginx будет 1.4

Comment: только дошло , вы без php это делаете ?

Comment: Чтобы nginx заработал php не нужен. Стартовая страница должна открыться без php и команды старта, рестарта работать, а тут ни в какую...:-(

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/#ubuntu-ppa лучше ставить из PPA. Там правильная интеграция с Ubuntu

Comment: @Alexey Ten Благодарю! Это оказался самый лучший вариант! Все конфиги подгрузились и правила для ufw. В варианте с репозитория разработчика такого не было. Можете сделать ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Ubuntu лучше ставить nginx из [PPA](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/#ubuntu-ppa). Он собран по гайдланам Debian/Ubuntu и лучше интергрирован с системой.

Answer (score 1):

Ну так убунта и говорит, что команда не найдена. SystemD на 15+ версиях убунты пошла. Запустить Nginx:

```
sudo service Nginx start
```

Comment: К сожалению эта команда тоже его не запускает. В логе пишет: 2016/06/13 07:53:45 [emerg] 4678#4678: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

Comment: Скорее всего стоит Apache 
netstat -tnlp | grep 80 
смотри кто висит на 80 порту. 
Можешь попробовать запустить sudo service apache stop

Comment: Апаче там точно нет, чистая убунту, уже раз 11 сношу в попытках разобраться. Есть мысль, что nginx 1.11.1 закрывает http и порты по умолчанию, когда с сайта разработчика качаю.

Comment: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use) 
Говорит, что кто-то висит на 80 порту, можешь в nginx.conf задать не 80 порт, а 8080 и запустить nginx.

Comment: На чистой системе по логике ничто не должно его занимать. Видимо брандмауэр его закрыл. Попробую еще раз переустановить убунту...

Comment: Чистая может быть и с полным фаршем уже установлена. Если ставите галку WebServer при установке

Comment: Можете скопировать вывод netstat -tnlp | grep 80

Comment: У хостинга в админ-панели запускаю переустановку. Дело в том, что с другими версиями убунту и nginx такого не было, а в таком сочетании версии, возникли проблемы...:-(

Comment: Данная команда ничего не вывела, просто перебросилась строка.

Comment: sudo ufw app list выдаёт только OpenSSH, а должна:  
  Nginx Full
  Nginx HTTP
  Nginx HTTPS
  OpenSSH Это я снова переустановил убунту, та же песня...

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list покажите содержимое.
Также скажите каким хостингом пользуетесь

Comment: Хостинг timeweb, бала бы там возможность установить ubuntu 16, проблем не было бы, на ней всё устанавливалось. http://imglink.ru/show-image.php?id=e50a6c898506655d09d64b59480c8312

Comment: Тут всё дело в том, что новый nginx не добавляет правила   Nginx Full
  Nginx HTTP
  Nginx HTTPS при установке.

Comment: а каким образом Вы устанавливаете nginx? Каким образом из репозитория разработчика?

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list это я показал до того как добавил туда пару строк: deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ trusty nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ trusty nginx
Как я понял вся проблема в том, что nginx при такой установке не добавляет правила для себя для utw. Гуглю, не могу найти как добавить их для него. Получается когда выключаю utw, nginx начинает работать.

Comment: https://community.timeweb.com/articles/nastroyka-vds-na-ubuntu-14-04-chast-5-ustanovka-i-nastroyka-nginx-1

Comment: По этой статье делаю, но не срастается с utw...:-(